# Cálculo do valor máximo para uma expressão de números naturais usando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dados dois naturais m e n determinar, entre todos os pares de números naturais
(x,y) tais que x < m e y < n, um par para o qual o valor da expressão
x*y - x**2 + y seja máximo e calcular também esse máximo.

Eu resolvi o problema assim:

```
m = int(input("Digite m: "))

n = int(input("Digite n: "))

#m = 2
#n =1
x = 0
y = 0
maximo =0
x_maximo = 0
y_maximo = 0
while x <m and y<n:
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):

            soma = i*j -i**2 +j
            print (soma)
            if soma > maximo:
                maximo = soma
                x_maximo = i
                y_maximo = j
    x +=1
    y +=1
print ("O máximo é {} para o par (x,y) = ({},{})". format(maximo,x_maximo,y_maximo))
```

Aparentemente, o algoritmo está correto mas eu achei que a solução não está muito elegante. Alguma sugestão de como melhorá-lo? Alguma maneira mais simples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De fato sua solução possui muito trabalho manual e alguns vícios de linguagem. Para facilitar o entendimento, vamos por parte, começando pela leitura dos valores de `m` e `n`:

```
m = int(input('m:'))
n = int(input('n:'))
```

Desta forma, pedimos ao usuário os valores, porém não tratamos completamente o valor. Ao converter para inteiro, temos que se a entrada não for um valor inteiro será levantada uma exceção, mas não nos preocupamos quando o valor é zero ou negativo (vamos supor que o usuário saiba que deve ser um valor positivo).

Para elaborar todos os pares de números naturais `(x, y)` tal que `x < m` e `y < n`, podemos utilizar a função `itertools.product` em conjunto com a função `range`:

```
pares = product(range(m), range(n))
```

O objeto `pares` será um gerador que poderá ser iterado para obter todos os pares possíveis. Já, para a expressão matemática, podemos utilizar uma *lambda*:

```
f = lambda x, y: x*y - x**2 + y
```

O único detalhe a ser cuidado aqui é que o nosso objeto `pares` gerará uma tupla de dois valores, enquanto a expressão `f` esperará dois valores como parâmetro, então teremos que utilizar a desconstrução de tuplas ao chamar a expressão.

Por fim, utilizando a função `max`, podemos obter o par que possui o máximo na expressão:

```
par = max(pares, key=lambda par: f(*par))
```

E, exibindo os resultados:

```
print('Par:', par)
print('Máximo:', f(*par))
```

O código final ficaria algo como:

```
from itertools import product

f = lambda x, y: x*y - x**2 + y

m = int(input("m: "))
n = int(input("n: "))

pares = product(range(m), range(n))

par = max(pares, key=lambda par: f(*par))

print('Par:', par)
print('Máximo:', f(*par))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/WoozyDifferentDictionaries)</sup>

Comment: O que seria lambda?

Comment: @EdS conceitualmente, a expressão *lambda* "é" uma função "anônima" que transforma uma entrada A em uma saída B.